# How to create features columns based on values across diff columns

Tags: csv, data-mining, orange

Hi I am trying to do one hot encoding in Orange in order to conduct market basket analysis.

Currently I have transaction data as follows in my CSV:

| C# | Items |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | Apple | Orange |  |
| C2 | Baby Milk | Apple | Orange |

I would like to find out what are the steps that I can do to process the data in orange or other software such that I am able to get this state for my data

| C# | Apple | Orange | Baby Milk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Currently when I try to preprocess the data in orange using "continous discrete variables - one feature per line" I get individual feature value columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely straightforward, but you could concatenate your products with comma or semicolon, pass it to Corpus, apply tokenization based on your concatenation character (comma, semicolon) with a Regex, then use Bag of Words from the Text add-on. I have tried it with Associate add-on, and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ive managed to solve it via pandas.

Sharing a google colab notebook of my code 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OxzXQa6mZskNUPlhNIH7_61XflbDGrvu?usp=sharing